# Battery-powered device: trade off between voltage and power requirements

Tags: switching, battery-operated

I'm designing a device that would be powered (LiPo I guess) by rechargeable batteries. They will be charged externally.

The power requirements are the following:

- the load runs at 12 V (pump and few solenoids)
- the peak current is about 1 A
- each operating cycle requires 5 minutes with a mean consumption of 500 mA
- the ideal target is to allow at least 20 cycles

If my math is not wrong, I need a battery with at least:

```
E = 500 mAh / 3600 s * 300 s * 20 = 830 mAh @ 12 V
```

Of course I need to put some cells in series or to use a step-up converter in order to reach the requested voltage.

What are the common rules to handle this tradeoff?

I'm tempted to use the standard 3S pack for RC models (but they sit to 11V).
Is there any technical advantage to use a step-up instead of adding cells?

Comment: I'd recommend with emphasis that you focus in a single cell and use a boost switcher. Assuming a single cell can meet your 20 cycle minimum or better, of course.

Comment: @periblepsis I'm interested in the technical reasons behind this. Would you please elaborate an answer (not opinion-based) about it?

Comment: Single cell charging and discharging Is preferred for reasons I suspect you know already, even if the same space is required and itself isn't yet another issue. Switchers are very efficient today. You get the exact voltage you want. Just thoughts. No time or inclination to pretend at more.

Comment: Add that the series pack requires added complexity -- a balancing circuit -- and that these circuits may cause a drain even when the device is in standby mode. (Aside: I've laptops where batteries drain *even when the PC is completely shut down*, for that reason. Annoying!)

Answer (score 1):

Your total ON time is 1.67 hours, so at 500mA, you require at least a battery capacity of 833mAh.

Series packs need a balancing circuit with additional quiescent current, that‘s why single or parallel packs and a step-up converter is the better solution.

Comment: Is the balancing circuit required also for discharging? AFAIK the common RC battery packs connect the balancing circuit to the charger only.

Comment: For discharging only, you do not need the balancing circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, since I stated the battery will be charged externally, it's still better to use a single (parallel) cell with a step-up?

Comment: You want some form of steady voltage, thats why the step up might be the best (=most efficient) solution.